# Creating a json for a post request

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to send JSON string to post method in order to receive flights information, i have the following json example i must modify to make different requests

```
{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "BOS",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
      },
      {
        "origin": "LAX",
        "destination": "BOS",
        "date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And i have the following class

```
public class Request {
    public class Passengers{
        private int adultCount;

        public int getAdultCount() {
            return adultCount;
        }

        public void setAdultCount(int adultCount) {
            this.adultCount = adultCount;
        }
    }

    private List<Slice> slice;

    public List<Slice> getSlice() {
        return slice;
    }

    public void setSlice(List<Slice> slice) {
        this.slice = slice;
    }


    public static class Slice{
        private String origin;
        private String destination;
        private String date;

        public String getOrigin() {
            return origin;
        }

        public void setOrigin(String origin) {
            this.origin = origin;
        }

        public String getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }

        public void setDestination(String destination) {
            this.destination = destination;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
}
```

how do i map this class to set the values and create a different json with the same format? i am trying with Jackson but im getting no suitable output

Comment: The simplest way, especially when you're first learning, is to forget about "POJOs" and just create a structure of Maps and Lists to mirror the desired JSON structure.  Just about any JSON toolkit will then be able to "serialize" that structure into JSON.  (Some kits use ArrayList and HashMap just fine, others prefer, say, JSONArray (List) and JSONObject (Map), but they're all basically the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the JSON format.](http://json.org/) Learn it well.

A JSON string maps to a Java `String`. A JSON number maps to a Java `Number` type. A JSON array maps to a `Collection` type or an array type. A JSON object maps to a Java `Map` type or any other Java type (not mentioned previously).

So a Java class like

```
class Foo {
    String name;
    int[] array;
    Map<String, List<Double>> ref;
}
```

maps to

```
{
    "name" : "string",
    "array" : [1, 2, 3],
    "ref" : {
        "val1" : [1.2, 3.4]
    }
}
```

Your JSON is a JSON object at the root. It contains

```
"request": {
```

which is a key value pair where the key is a JSON string and the value is a JSON object.

This should tell you that you need a Java object with a field named `request` which should be referencing another object. Do this analysis recursively and you will get your Java Object formats.

Answer (score 0):

It would greatly simplify your life using Gson, a json library from google wich makes all parsing/encoding based o your class diagram. It also supports recursivity wich let you define more complex structures such arraylist, list, hashtable. Everything works by its self.

```
private String field = "field_1";
priavate String field2 = "field_2";
ArraList<FIELDS> field_list = new ArrayList<FIELDS>();
```

Would traduce to :

```
{
  field : "field_1",
  field2 : "field_2"
  field_list : [
    etc...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you saying Jackson can't do this?

Comment: They said they use Jackson. Jackson already has all the capabilities you've listed in your answer.